# Userid in azure datalake (gen2) log

Tags: azure, logging, azure-data-lake, userid, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am getting my head around the logs in Azure, and particularly the logs I get from ADSL Gen2 data lake.
It is really true that I can't get the login / userid for the changes to the data lake?

I have these fields

> TenantId TimeGenerated [UTC] AccountName Location Protocol
> OperationName
> **AuthenticationType** StatusCode StatusText DurationMs ServerLatencyMs Uri
> **CallerIpAddress** CorrelationId SchemaVersion OperationVersion AuthenticationHash UserAgentHeader ClientRequestId Etag ServiceType
> RequestHeaderSize ResponseHeaderSize LastModifiedTime [UTC] Category
> TlsVersion SourceSystem Type
> _ResourceId

AuthenticationType is just called *AccountKey*

CallerIpAddress is the IP address of the user

But the userID like 123@domain.com or similar is what I am looking for. So how do I include [fields that describe how the operation was authenticated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/monitor-blob-storage-reference#fields-that-describe-how-the-operation-was-authenticated)

**To be clear** *(after some input from KarthikBhyresh-MT)*

I have my own ADSL that I am playing around in
In azure portal under ADSL > **Diagnostic setting (classic)** I have enabled Blob logging version 2.0, Read/Write/Delete/Delete data *(just as suggested)*

I then use Microsoft Azure Storage Explore to upload some file, deleting some of the files again, and generally make something to log

In azure portal under ADSL > **Logs (preview)** I read the StorageBlobLogs

If I run the simplest query where RequesterUpn is not empty I get my username for an even where AuthenticationType is OAuth. That is the login to the service.

But when I find the OperationName: DeleteFile I have no information of who did it
I have the autenticationHash(1) and CallerIpAdress(2) and I could look up the IpAdress from the OAuth log event to put Delete action to a name
[image]

Comment: UserPrincipalName [string] - User principal name used in bearer authorization.  Example: `testuser@azure.onmicrosoft.com`

Comment: I found the list of *Fields that describe how the operation was authenticated* that includes *requester / upn The User Principal Name (UPN) of requestor. For example: someone@contoso.com.*  but they are all empty in the log

Comment: it would be empty if the request was unsucceful or anonymous or a SAS request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I had sat *Allow storage account key access* to **Disabled**. I had OAuth on every StorageRead, StorageWrite, StorageDelete

[image]

[MS Dokumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/shared-key-authorization-prevent?tabs=portal#remediate-authorization-via-shared-key)

Answer (score 1):

If you have turned on the below specifics in ADLS account

[image]

Optionally route if needed

[image]

I can see from the logs in the storage about ADLS now.

A sample record containing **upn**. You can find it at `identity.upn` where **OAuth** is the authorization used, which is supported **Version 2.0** of Storage Analytics logging.

```
{
    "time": "2021-10-30T05:12:17.3923930Z",
    "resourceId": "/subscriptions/<Subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account-name>/blobServices/default",
    "category": "StorageRead",
    "operationName": "GetBlobServiceProperties",
    "operationVersion": "2020-08-04",
    "schemaVersion": "1.0",
    "statusCode": 200,
    "statusText": "Success",
    "durationMs": 712,
    "callerIpAddress": "<ip-address><port>",
    "correlationId": "fced83b0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cd769c000000",
    "identity": {
        "type": "OAuth",
        "tokenHash": "E098F823BC1BE1D9AC73F22F82xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5537E013A5E6BDF71E",
        "requester": {
            "appId": "691458b9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ed83a7f1b41c",
            "audience": "https://storage.azure.com/",
            "objectId": "b1c5060f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-31cce61160f4",
            "tenantId": "72f988bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2d7cd011db47",
            "tokenIssuer": "https://sts.windows.net/72f988bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2d7cd011db47/",
            "upn": "user@domain.com"
        }
    },
    "location": "East US",
    "properties": {
        "accountName": "<storage-account-name>",
        "userAgentHeader": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36 Edg/95.0.1020.30",
        "serviceType": "blob",
        "objectKey": "/<storage-account-name>",
        "serverLatencyMs": 711,
        "requestHeaderSize": 2713,
        "responseHeaderSize": 282,
        "responseBodySize": 802,
        "tlsVersion": "TLS 1.2"
    },
    "uri": "https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net:443/?restype=service&comp=properties&_=1635xxxx35961",
    "protocol": "HTTPS",
    "resourceType": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices"
}
```

Refer official MS [Storage Analytics log format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-log-format#set-logging-version) doc for more details.

Example record for `"category": "StorageWrite"`

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is excellent @karthikbhyresh-mt! That gives me the login into the datalake. But I was hoping to link operation, like read/write/delete/add file to a upn.

Comment: yea, you can find them under `category` In my example it is `StorageRead`

Comment: I just looked up another log file for write operation. `    "category": "StorageWrite",
    "operationName": "PutBlob",`

Comment: I have updated my original question based on KarthikBhyresh-MT answers